# How can I update records found with except in SQL

Tags: sql-server, compare

I'm comparing (one-way) two tables of different databases in SQL.
I want to update only the second table with the differences.
The comparing part gives me the correct results, but I have no clue how to get these result in the updating part

```
-- The comparing part DB1 with DB2
    WITH RecordsWithUpdates AS
    (SELECT DeviceID, DeviceName, DeviceNumber, Active FROM DB1.dbo.devices
    EXCEPT
    SELECT DeviceID, DeviceName, DeviceNumber, Active FROM DB2.dbo.devices
    )

    -- displaying the differences
    Select * from DB2.dbo.Devices
    WHERE DeviceID IN (SELECT DeviceID FROM RecordsWithUpdates)

    -- Updating then columns of DB2
    Update DB2.dbo.devices SET DeviceName = ?????, SET DeviceNumber = ??????, Active = ???????
```

The Code part with the ????? is where it should insert the found differences, but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: What is the primary key on your tables? Looking at the code, I understand it's not just `DeviceID`, otherwise the `select` query would never return anything. This will determine the join conditions for the `update`, or you risk ending up with multiple indistinguishable rows after it.

Comment: The Primary Key on both tables is DeviceID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this with the `UPDATE ... SET ... FROM ... JOIN` syntax, like:

```
UPDATE 
    t2
SET 
    t2.DeviceName   = t1.DeviceName,
    t2.DeviceNumber = t1.DeviceNumber,
    t2.Active       = t1.Active
FROM 
    DB2.dbo.devices t2
    INNER JOIN DB1.dbo.devices t1 
        ON  t1.DeviceID = t2.DeviceID
        AND NOT (
            t1.DeviceName       = t2.DeviceName
            AND t1.DeviceNumber = t2.DeviceNumber
            AND t1.Active       = t2.Active 
        )
```

---

If you want at the same time to `INSERT` records that do not yet exists, then you can use the `MERGE` syntax instead:

```
MERGE DB2.dbo.devices t2 
USING DB1.dbo.devices t1 
ON (t1.DeviceID = t2.DeviceID)
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET
        t2.DeviceName   = t1.DeviceName,
        t2.DeviceNumber = t1.DeviceNumber,
        t2.Active       = t1.Active
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN INSERT(DeviceID, DeviceName, DeviceNumber, Active)
    VALUES (t1.DeviceID, t1.DeviceName, t1.DeviceNumber, t1.Active)
```

Finally: if you want to delete the records that exist in `t2` but not in `t1`, just add this at the end of the `MERGE` query:

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
THEN DELETE;
```

Comment: Thank GMB this works for DeviceID's that exist in both tables!
But how can I change the code to insert a new line in T2 if T1 had a new record created that does not already exist in T1?

Comment: @Karstieman: ah ok, this was not obviouis in your question. I updated my answer with a solution that uses `MERGE`.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot!!
This was the exactly what I was looking for.